# Error with curl when installing MRI through RVM

Tags: ruby, curl, rvm

Can someone please explain this to me? RVM installed properly but when I want to install MRI Ruby through RVM, I get this error.

```
[user@p31]~% rvm install 1.9.3
Installing Ruby from source to: /path/to/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
There was an error, please check /path/to/user/.rvm/log//*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying ftp:// URL instead.

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
There was an error, please check /path/to/user/.rvm/log//*.log
There has been an error while trying to fetch the source.  
Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

I get the same error in bash, zsh and csh.

My `extract.log` has only one line in it.

```
tar xmzf /u/b/ogbuluij/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /u/b/ogbuluij/.rvm/src --no-same-owner
```

Comment: check this post out - midway through he mentions the same issue: http://www.wiredatom.com/blog/2012/06/01/ruby-on-rails-install-with-bad-interpreter-errors/

Comment: I tried it and it got me through installing 1.8.7 on rvm

Comment: i saw another post about updating RVM. I did that and it worked. Thanks nonetheless!